# Accessing the HTML5 Canvas's DrawingContext2D Save/Restore Stack?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, drawingcontext

Is there a way to access the HTML `Canvas` element's `DrawingContext2D` `save` and `restore` stack under the hood?

The purpose would be to `save` a base state, `clip` a region of it off, allow some operations to take place which may apply `clip`, `save`, `restore` with indeterminate orders (i.e. something might `save` 2-3 states to the stack and never restore them or it might `restore` multiple times and lose the original `save` state prior to going back to the parent function which would then be attempting to `restore` a state which no longer exists in the stack.)

I'd prefer to do this without a wrapper class around the `DrawingContext2D` since JavaScript gets a little slower with each function call and rendering tends to be time-sensitive.

It would also be great to be able to limit the number of `restore` calls possible in the called function without relying on the called function to maintain that limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to access the HTML Canvas element's DrawingContext2D save and restore stack under the hood?

The state stack is internal and not exposed in any way. You can tap into the save/restore calls themselves by promoting your own calls as wrappers on the context *prototype* (see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964215/how-to-delete-the-state-stack-for-a-javascript-canvas-rendering-context/36998524#36998524) which shows one approach) and from there keep count track - this won't affect the rest of the context performance-wise. And of course you still won't have access to the internals. There would be some caveats though such as how do you differentiate call source and how will you know when a call should be allowed or not (calling `restore()` more than `save()` is btw. safe).

However, if possible I would avoid using save/restore at all. Most states can be tracked "manually" by only tracking or setting the states you actually need including transformations (`setTransform()` is very handy here).

The major obstacle is when using clipping. There is currently no way to reset clipping without using save/restore (or set size of the context) - the [standard includes it](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-resetclip) but it doesn't seem to be supported by any vendors at this time. However, in many cases you can replace clipping by using compositing instead, sometimes combined with off-screen canvases.

Comment: [webkit said no](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82801) because [*A library*] "*can’t draw outside of the clip you specified. With resetClip(), that JS library can draw
wherever the heck it wants...*" [comment #25](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82801#c25) This poor guy doesn't know the `canvas.width=canvas.width` trick for *evil libs* and doesn't tell us how we *are probably doing it wrong* when we just want to reset the clipping area and not all the other properties of the context...

Comment: @Kaiido `resetClip` doesn't exist in `Chrome`, not sure about other browsers.  Any idea when it makes it to production?

Comment: @K3N Thanks, I hadn't considered off-screen `canvas` elements but that's probably the way to go.

Comment: @CoryG the feature request I linked to was made in 2012 (when chrome was still with webkit) and got status declined in 2014 (IIRC chrome was still in webkit at this moment too). I couldn't find anything on mozilla's bugzilla, but I would say that no one is working on it on any implementation. You could try to make new FR to all these browser's teams, but currently, don't expect it to makes it way in a near future.